# Storing images to CoreData - Swift

Tags: ios, image, swift, core-data, nsdata

In my code I managed to save a textLabel with CoreData but I can't seem to properly save the image. I've read some tutorials and I know I have to convert it to NSData. But how do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Core Data isn't meant to save big binary files like images. Use Document Directory in file system instead.

Here is sample code to achieve that.

```
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first as! String
// self.fileName is whatever the filename that you need to append to base directory here.
let path = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(self.fileName)
let success = data.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
if !success { // handle error }
```

It is recommended to save `filename` part to core data along with other meta data associated with that image and retrieve from file system every time you need it.

edit: also note that from ios8 onwards, persisting full file url is invalid since sandboxed app-id is dynamically generated. You will need to obtain `documentsDirectory` dynamically as needed.

Comment: this is a convoluted solution please refer to @Max_Power89 below for a modernized approach.

Answer (score 18):

You shouldn't save large data inside core data, an Apple engineer told me this little trick at the last WWDC:

You can use the property "Allows external storage":

[image]

By doing this as far as i know, your image will be stored somewhere in the file system, and inside core data will be saved a link to your picture in the file system. every time you'll ask for the picture, core data will automatically retrive the image from the file system.

To save the image as NSData you can do:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImage")
let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0))
managedObject?.setValue(imageData, forKey: "YourKey")
```

Remember that 1.0 in the UIImageJPEGRepresentatio means that your using the best quality and so the image will be large and heavy:

> The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0
>   to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest
>   quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best
>   quality).

Comment: @zaph sorry my mistake, you are right. I've updated it

Comment: With "Allows External Storage" also set the Attribute Type to Binary Data. But from what I have read, which may be out-of-date, there are downsides including migration and iCloud–so beware.

Comment: and how to read that image form core data and put it into tableview cell?

Comment: Is it possible for the user to delete this image from outside of the application (i.e. is the photo simply available for deletion in the photo library)?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go for JPEG and for PNG you just use UIImagePNGRepresentation:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "YourImage")
let imageData = NSData(data: UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0))
managedObject?.setValue(imageData, forKey: "YourKey")
```

Comment: A compression value of 1.0 can be very expensive size-wise. Also worth considering is `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.

Comment: I know that - he is clearly asking how to store it, other than that he should read into how to use the properties etc. Your point below is valid as well @zaph.

Comment: Please consider my comment as an addition, not in any way complaining about or minimizing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Generally large data objects are not stored in a database or Core Data. Instead save the images in the Document directory (or a sub-directory) and save the file name in Core Data.

Se the answer by @Valentin on how to create a data representation of an image.

Save it with `func writeToFile(_ path: String, atomically atomically: Bool) -> Bool`

Comment: @zaph could you point us to a good tutorial on how to get the image reference and for fetchRequest, how to get the image location? regards