# Add cell to favorites tableview with core data

Tags: swift, uitableview, favorites

I have an iOS app that I would like to have people swipe on a tableview cell to add that cell to the favorites page tableview.

It would have to use core data so that the favorites save after app exit.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is what I have so far for the cell swipe action:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favorite") { (action, indexPath) in
        // share item at indexPath
        self.editing = false
        print("Favorited \(indexPath.row)")


    }

    favorite.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    return [favorite]
}
```

This is my code for the favorites page.

```
var favorites : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    favorites = vars.favs
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return favorites.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let object = favorites[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = object 
    return cell
}
```

This is a picture of how the favorites will be added:
[image: Current Progress]

Comment: Could you please show us what you have done so far?

Comment: I only have the swipe action setup for the cells so far.

Comment: If you have a table view, you must have some functions for tableviews. Show us those

Comment: Ill update the question in a few minutes

Comment: Penatheboss the initial tableview is a static one and there is no code associated with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a list of favourites as Strings is all you need to persist in your app, you might be able to simply use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html) instead of Core Data.

To save an array of favorites:

```
let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Favorite") { (action, indexPath) in
    var favorites : [String] = []
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let favoritesDefaults : AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey("favorites") {
        favorites = favoritesDefaults! as [String]
    }

    favorites.append(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).textLabel!.text)
    defaults.setObject(favorites, forKey: "favorites")
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

To read the array of favorites in your favorites page:

```
var favorites : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let favoritesDefaults : AnyObject? = defaults.objectForKey("favorites") {
        favorites = favoritesDefaults! as [String]
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Will this also transfer the pictures?

Comment: @Jacksmackod You can save the path to the picture, which will be stored elsewhere on disk. Even with core data though, it's not recommended to save images directly inside it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30672362/1420793 . 

I had in mind at first though that you'd only need to save an ID or something similar which references the content of the cell that was favourited. Will your cell only have an image, or a more complex data structure? If it's only an image, the method above would still work. If however you want to save more data, then indeed core data would be a better choice.

Comment: I want the cell to keep the text picture and also its action (changing the view)

Comment: Sorry I cannot get this to work. Could you please write the implementation for it as well?

Comment: I might need this really dumbed down

Comment: @Jacksmackod I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the cell's action, can you update your original post with your cellForRowAtIndexPath and/or willDisplayCell tableview methods to have a better idea?

Comment: Yeah I can do that

Comment: @Jacksmackod I updated my answer, let me know how that works for you

Comment: it says "ambiguous reference to member 'tableview' " at favorites.append(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath).textLabel!.text)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113356/discussion-between-jeremy-rea-and-jacksmackod).