# Save tableViewItem in defaults when tableViewCell is swiped left

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, default

I followed [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37513754/add-cell-to-favorites-tableview-with-core-data.) answer to save my data in an array when swipe left and the favorite button is clicked. I have done so far is this

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { (action, indexPath) in
        var favorites : [String] = []
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let favoritesDefaults : AnyObject? = defaults.object(forKey: "favorites") as AnyObject {
            favorites = favoritesDefaults! as! [String]
        }

        let cell   = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        favorites.append(itemList[indexPath.row])
        defaults.set(favorites, forKey: "favorites")
        defaults.synchronize()
        }
    return [favorite]
    }
```

Array List

```
   var itemList = [ "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", 
                  "item6", "item7", "item8", "item" , "item", "Gobbling"]
```

when i click the favorite button it gives the error

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x22e386f28) to 'NSArray' (0x22e386960)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't dequeue cells outside of `cellForRowAt`. Never do that. The cell is unused anyway.

Use the dedicated API `array(forKey` to read the array from `UserDefaults` and cast the type to the expected type rather than unspecified `Any(Object)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let favorite = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { [unowned self] (action, indexPath) in
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        var favorites = defaults.array(forKey: "favorites") as? [String] ?? []
        favorites.append(self.itemList[indexPath.row])
        defaults.set(favorites, forKey: "favorites")
    }
    return [favorite]
}
```

Comment: The error message disappeared but it doesn't save the data. after marking many rows as favorite and then after printing the data as         print(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "favorites"))
it print nil value

Comment: The code appends only the item at the given index path. If you want to save multiple items you have to filter the datasource array to get the favorite items and append them

Comment: yes i want to save multiple items in defaults can you please update your answer.

Comment: No I can't because I don't know how to get the cells marked as favorite. You have to change the data model to a struct to save also the favorite status of each row.

Comment: sir the code above do not save even the current indexpath.row. even a single word

Comment: This is rather impossible. If `itemList` contains a string at the given index it must be saved. Is `itemList` the data source array?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200434/discussion-between-sajjad-ahmad-and-vadian).