# CoreData adding new objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am using CoreData to save 5 images from my server, so when I launch my app I load the 5 images from coreData AND then after that I download the newest images from my server.

So I would like to be able to update those 5 images already saved to coreData with the 5 Newest images downloaded from the server.

So far what I am doing is clearing/emptying the coreData each time I download from the server, and once I have finished downloading from the server I add the newest 5 to the CoreData.

I don't think that is the best way, so I'm kind of looking for some professional advice, on how to update the previous saved 5 images with the lates 5?!

Thanks in advance to any help you can offer me!

Comment: i would better advise to store image in Sandbox memory of app(ie. Documents directory), and just store name/path of image in coredata. Display images from coredata using path, download new images from server save to sandbox memory, update image name/path in coredata and reload images using updated path. Storing images in coredata would impact on performance.

Comment: What kind of performance? make it slower? Sorry just started doing coreData a weeks a go...

Comment: Yes impact on your main thread and UI. Reading/Writing blob data from coredata would require transform as well as it will make your persistence store heavy in terms of memory size.

Comment: Hmm, So you say using sandbox is best... Quick question, What do you think instagram does for there homepage?

Comment: I don't know what tools/technique Instagram is using, but with my experience and knowledge i can say its definitely not storing images in coredata. It would keep all the assets in app sandbox memory rather keeping it in any db.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Ok, thanks for that. I shall look in to it a let you know

Comment: @DipenPanchasara just did a quick search and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671967/storing-images-to-coredata-swift/30673104#30673104 I am storing the images like that answer shows, with external storage option. What do you think?

Comment: Its the same concept i mentioned, but its managed by coredata while in my solution developer need to manage retrieval & storage. You can use it.

Comment: Ok I'm still looking into sandbox and will see if it makes any difference