# Most efficient way to store an often changed array of array of images in core data

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimage

So I have been doing research on how to store an array of images and I am currently using an extension method suggested in another stack overflow post.

```
extension Array where Element: UIImage {
    // Given an array of UIImages return a Data representation of the array suitable for storing in core data as binary data that allows external storage
    func coreDataRepresentation() -> ImageArrayRepresentation? {
        let CDataArray = NSMutableArray()

        for img in self {
            guard let imageRepresentation = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img) else {
                print("Unable to represent image as PNG")
                return nil
            }
            let data : NSData = NSData(data: imageRepresentation)
            CDataArray.add(data)
        }

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: CDataArray)
    }
}

extension ImageArrayRepresentation {
    // Given a Data representation of an array of UIImages return the array
    func imageArray() -> ImageArray? {
        if let mySavedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: self) as? NSArray {
            // TODO: Use regular map and return nil if something can't be turned into a UIImage
            let imgArray = mySavedData.compactMap({
                return UIImage(data: $0 as! Data)
            })
            return imgArray
        }
        else {
            print("Unable to convert data to ImageArray")
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

So then when I save the array I simply use `images.coreDataRepresentation()` and store it in a binary data attribute of my entity.

My fear is that as the array may contain upwards of 900 images, and that constantly saving all of this data would result in delays. I was thinking that using a system similar to that of relational databases where I keep a separate core data entity to hold solely these photos with a relationship based on id, however, after doing more research I found that this is not advised with core data. Is there a better way to do this? Or is one of these methods superior?

Comment: How big are the images? Have you tested with 900 images to see how it performs?

Comment: @MikeTaverne the images are taken directly from the camera or the photo library so depending on what version of iPhone the picture size may vary. It is also possible that there will be more than 900 images, although it will likely be uncommon.

Comment: @joshLor Wouldn’t it be better to store _images_ inside `Documents Directory` and store a _reference_ to them inside **Core Data entity’s attribute**

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi What advantage does this give over just saving in core data

Comment: @joshLor `Core Data` is not generally used for storing _multimedia content_, as it is mainly for textual data and data that does not amount to too much in a single entry(like in a row) . On the other hand,`Documents Directory`,`Tmp Directory` are all there for multimedia content such as _audio, video_ and _images_ . **I am not so sure** about faster retrieval from _Documents Directory_ as compared to _Core Data_ in case of _images_ but I think _Documents Directory_ is faster. Plus it's a standard way of storing images. Plus you said you have 900 images, _Documents Directory_ will be a safe bet

Comment: You can refer to the following for more --  [Storing images to Core Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30671967/storing-images-to-coredata-swift)